# Dynamically filtering a CollectionViewSource bound to a SelectedItem via MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been digging back into some projects in WPF, and come across a hurdle that I haven't been able to find a directly related solution for.

Essentially I want to filter a child property of a SelectedItem dynamically (via text entered in the filter box, something along the lines of `.Contains(filter)`). The UI displays correctly in the sample project, but after attempting to implement solutions from every hit possible on SO or otherwise, I've come up blank, or making serious compromises to the MVVM pattern.

**ParentItem:**

```cs
public class ParentItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> ChildItems { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ParentItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ParentItemStatus
    {
        Status_One,
        Status_Two
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ParentItem> ParentItems { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ParentItems = new ObservableCollection<ParentItem>();

            LoadDummyParentItems();
        }

        private ICommand _filterChildrenCommand;
        public ICommand FilterChildrenCommand => _filterChildrenCommand ?? (_filterChildrenCommand = new RelayCommand(param => FilterChildren((string)param), param => CanFilterChildren((string)param)));

        private bool CanFilterChildren(string filter)
        {
            //TODO: Check for selected item in real life.
            return filter.Length > 0;
        }

        private void FilterChildren(string filter)
        {
            //TODO: Filter?
        }

        private void LoadDummyParentItems()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ParentItems.Add(new ParentItem()
                {
                    Name = $"Parent Item {i}",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddHours(i),
                    IsActive = i % 2 == 0 ? true : false,
                    Status = i % 2 == 0 ? ParentItemStatus.Status_Two : ParentItemStatus.Status_One,
                    ChildItems = new List<string>() { $"Child one_{i}", $"Child two_{i}", $"Child three_{i}", $"Child four_{i}" }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="FilteringDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilteringDemo.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.ChildItems}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="ItemList" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.CreatedOn}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.IsActive}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.Status}" Margin="2"/>
            </Grid>

            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ChildItemsViewSource}}" />

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Contains:" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ChildFilterInput" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Filter" Width="100" Margin="2" Command="{Binding FilterChildrenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ChildFilterInput, Path=Text}"/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've tried various implementations of adding a `Filter` event handler on the `CollectionViewSource` but have been unable to make them dynamic. It also seems like most examples/tutorials only deal directly with the parent item or static filters.

In a non-MVVM mindset, I was thinking to have an interaction trigger drive the selected item back into the ViewModel, and then create a filtered ICollectionView which the ChildItems ListView would bind to, but it seems like I can't be the only person trying this, and that there must be an easier MVVM binding friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the examples from @BionicCode- I added a SelectedParentItem INPC property to the ViewModel, performed the filtering on that via `CollectionViewSource.Filter`, and bound the ChildItems `ListView` to `SelectedParentItem.ChildItems`.

I did not bind the text box property changed to a backing field in the VM as per @BionicCode's example, as the "real" ChildItems might be in the mid 10,000's and I didn't want it to filter on each keystroke. So this answer implements the filter button and text box command, and the CanFilterChildren is doing a proper null check.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ParentItem> ParentItems { get; set; }

        private ParentItem _selectedParentItem;
        public ParentItem SelectedParentItem
        {
            get { return _selectedParentItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedParentItem, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ParentItems = new ObservableCollection<ParentItem>();

            LoadDummyParentItems();
        }

        private ICommand _filterChildrenCommand;
        public ICommand FilterChildrenCommand => _filterChildrenCommand ?? (_filterChildrenCommand = new RelayCommand(param => FilterChildren((string)param), param => CanFilterChildren((string)param)));

        private bool CanFilterChildren(string filter) => SelectedParentItem != null && filter.Length > 0;

        private void FilterChildren(string filter)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SelectedParentItem.ChildItems).Filter = item => (item as string).Contains(filter);
        }

        private void LoadDummyParentItems()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ParentItems.Add(new ParentItem()
                {
                    Name = $"Parent Item {i}",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddHours(i),
                    IsActive = i % 2 == 0 ? true : false,
                    Status = i % 2 == 0 ? ParentItemStatus.Status_Two : ParentItemStatus.Status_One,
                    ChildItems = new List<string>() { $"Child one_{i}", $"Child two_{i}", $"Child three_{i}", $"Child four_{i}" }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            this.DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```xml
<Window x:Class="FilteringDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilteringDemo.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="ItemList" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParentItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.CreatedOn}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.IsActive}" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemList, Path=SelectedItem.Status}" Margin="2"/>
            </Grid>

            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedParentItem.ChildItems}" />

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox x:Name="ChildFilterInput" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding FilterChildrenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ChildFilterInput, Path=Text}" Key="Return" />
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Filter" Width="100" Margin="2" Command="{Binding FilterChildrenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ChildFilterInput, Path=Text}"/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**:

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
            {
                field = newValue;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**RelayCommand.cs**:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Predicate<object> _canExecuteMethod;
        private Action<object> _executeMethod;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Predicate<object> canExecuteMethod = null)
        {
            _executeMethod = executeMethod;
            _canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecuteMethod == null ? true : _canExecuteMethod(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _executeMethod(parameter);
        }
    }
```

**ParentItem.cs**:

```cs
public class ParentItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> ChildItems { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ParentItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ParentItemStatus
    {
        Status_One,
        Status_Two
    }
```

**App.xaml**:

```xml
<Application x:Class="FilteringDemo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilteringDemo"
             StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Note:** The `MainWindow.xaml` file was moved into a "Views" folder, so I'm including the `App.xaml` with the updated StartupUri in case anyone is trying to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

The following example shows a simple solution to implement live filtering on a collection:

**Person.cs**

```
class Person
{
  public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
  }

  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
    {
      new Person("Derek", "Zoolander"),
      new Person("Tony", "Montana"),
      new Person("John", "Wick"),
      new Person("The", "Dude"),
      new Person("James", "Bond"),
      new Person("Walter", "White")
    };
  }

  private void FilterData(string filterPredicate)
  {
    // Execute live filter
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Persons).Filter =
        item => (item as Person).FirstName.StartsWith(filterPredicate, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }

  private string searchPredicate;   
  public string SearchPredicate
  {
    get => this.searchFilter;
    set 
    { 
      this.searchPredicate = value;
      FilterData(value);
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchPredicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"} />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Firstname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
          </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

### Update

It seems like you are having problems to filter the child items. The following example is more specific to your scenario:

**DataItem.cs**

```
class DataItem
{
  public DataItem(string Name)
  {
    this.Name = name;
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<DataItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.ParentItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>()
    {
      new DataItem("Ben Stiller") { ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>() { new DataItem("Zoolander"), new DataItem("Tropical Thunder") }},
      new DataItem("Al Pacino") { ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>() { new DataItem("Scarface"), new DataItem("The Irishman") }},
      new DataItem("Keanu Reeves") { ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>() { new DataItem("John Wick"), new DataItem("Matrix") }},
      new DataItem("Bryan Cranston") { ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>() { new DataItem("Breaking Bad"), new DataItem("Malcolm in the Middle") }}
    };
  }

  private void FilterData(string filterPredicate)
  {
    // Execute live filter
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.SelectedParentItem.ChildItems).Filter =
        item => (item as DataItem).Name.StartsWith(filterPredicate, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }

  private string searchPredicate;   
  public string SearchPredicate
  {
    get => this.searchFilter;
    set 
    { 
      this.searchPredicate = value;
      FilterData(value);
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<DataItem> ParentItems { get; set; }
  public DataItem SelectedParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParentItem}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchPredicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedParentItem.ChildItems}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put together a few examples. I was able to wire everything up with some slight modifications. Notability that the ```SelectedParentItem``` property on the VM needed to implement INPC so that it was being updated accordingly.